# How can I retrieve a certain view (textField) and its value?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

So my problem is that I have created some views in xcode by code (not the interface builder) and set specific tags for each one this is the code that I used to create NSTextField

```
NSTextField* textField;
for(int i=1; i<someNumber; i++)
{
   frame = ...;
   textField = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame: frame];
   textField.tag = i;
   [self.window.contentView addSubview: textField];
   textField.target = self;
}
```

as you can see I'm not saving each textField, and at some point I would like to retrieve specific views to use their values later. So my questions are:

1. How can I retrieve the views with only the tag number?
2. How can I get the value of the textFields after I've retrieved them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get view with specified tag you can use `viewWithTag:`. To get text you can use `stringValue`.

```
NSTextField *textField = (NSTextField *)[self.window.contentView viewWithTag:1];
NSLog(@"%@", [textField stringValue]);
```